# условные операторы

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста почему при условии `a != b && c` IDEA говорит что operator && can not be applied to boolian, int. Вроде a,b,c обозначены как int.

Comment: a != b становиться boolean, а c остается int. int с boolean не сравниваються.

Comment: Если они все числа, то как вообще определить результат этого выражения?  Допустим, все три равны 2, что тогда ожидается в результате?

Comment: a!=b && a!=c попробуйте так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь сравнить **результат сравнения** `a` и `b` с **переменной** `c`. Для лучшего понимания того, что я имею в виду, расставим скобки.
 `(a != b) && c`, то есть, пологая результат выражения `(a != b) == true`, а `int c = 1` ваше выражение будет выглядеть так: `true && 1`
Т.к. все переменные у вас имеют тип int, то получается, что после сравнения `a != b` вы получаете результат `boolean` true/false, а затем пытаетесь этот `boolean` сравнить с `int c`. В Java нельзя сравнивать `int` с `boolean` (подробнее можно узнать, что с чем сравнивается, почитав про приведение типов), переменные примитивного типа `boolean` принимают значения только `true` или `false` и их нельзя привести к цифрам (0 или 1), так же как и цифры (0 или 1) нельзя привести к true/false. Более того, вы не сможете привести оберточный тип Boolean к значению, если будете пытаться сделать это не от строки, равной `"true"` или `"false"` (то есть можете попытаться, но всегда будете получать `false`).